# Very slow RUN on docker on windows containers

Tags: windows, docker, containers, chocolatey

I installed docker on a Windows 10 machine via chocolatey
`choco install docker-desktop`

Then I have built this image

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2016
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]

RUN Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1 | Invoke-Expression
```

And it runs reasonably fast

Then I try to run this one

```
FROM chocolatey
SHELL ["powershell", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop';"]

RUN cinst -y netfx-4.7.2-devpack
```

After downloading the .net installer the process fails with timeout.
The last thing in the log is `Installing dotnetfx...`

No idea why and how to debug.
Anyone has the same issue? Where do I start debugging this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont have a definitive answer for this but my current workaround is to use the sdk base image from microsoft from https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-sdk/